# How to list content that references another content type through paragraphs

Tags: views, 9, paragraphs

I have two content types: "Author" and "Document." The Document content type uses a Paragraph "Author_citation" to connect the two and display all the authors (plus other fields) that worked on that Document in a block. This works fine.

I also want to show a block - on the "Author" page - listing documents connected to that author, through the paragraph.

I know I've seen a way in the past to pull this with views. But I'm not finding the answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Paragraphs does not have proper views integration. I don't think that this can be done. But hopefully someone will come along and prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Whoohoo! I figured it out! Here's a description, using my first Content type ('document') containing a paragraph ('citation') that has an entity reference to a second content type ('author'). While showing all authors on Document is easy, to show all documents connected to that author, do this:

1. In the view, under Advanced options, create a reference to the paragraph, ie, "field_citation: Paragraph"
2. Create a second reference, "(field_citation: Paragraph) field_author: Content." Set its reference in the dropdown to the 1st relationship in step one.
3. Set a contextual filter of ID, and set its relationship to  (field_author: Content) Choose 'Provide Default Value: from URL'

That's pretty much it. place the views block on the "authors" page, and it works!